# Facebook Ad Management Python SDK returns "GraphMethodException"

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to do a simple get of stats of ad campaigns.  I thre this together from the documentation:

```
from facebookads.objects import AdUser
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.objects import AdAccount

my_app_id = 'xxx'
my_app_secret = 'xxx'
my_access_token = 'xxx'
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

me = AdUser(fbid='xxx')
account = AdAccount('xxx')

params =  {
    'start_date': '2014-09-01',
}

fields = {
    'impressions',
    'clicks',
    'spent',
}

stats = account.get_ad_campaign_stats(fields=fields, params=params)

for stat in stats:
    print stat
```

I am getting back a code:1 type: GraphMethodException back from the API.

The response loos like this:

```
Message: Call was not successful
Method:  GET
Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/xxx/adcampaignstats
Params:  {'fields': 'impressions,spent,clicks', 'start_date': '2014-09-01', 'summary': 'true'}

Status:  400
Response:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
    "code": 100, 
    "type": "GraphMethodException"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: looks like a bug in the 2.3 version of the python SDK, as the correct path is /stats not /adcampaignstats. However, this API is soon to be deprecated, so you should upgrade to the 2.4 version of the SDK and use the insights endpoint instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will update my sdk.

Comment: adaccount/adcampaignstats does exist in v2.3 but is deprecated in v2.4 so this call should work for you.

There is a possibility that your access token does not have the required permissions to access the reporting aspect of the ad account.